# When I am adding fragment to my view pager (in nested scroll view), I can not exit from application with device back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, back-button, android-nestedscrollview

This is my activity_main code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/app_name">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <com.duolingo.open.rtlviewpager.RtlViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to add some fragments to ViewPager in NestedScrollView.
Without adding fragments to ViewPager everything is ok and I can exit from app by device back button, but when I am adding fragment(s) to ViewPager I can not exit from app by pressing device back button.(Back button is working and for example can close soft keyboard)

this is my fragment code:
(empty fragment!)

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
    ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jadvalyab,container,false);
}
```

and this is my adapter:

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> fragsTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment,String title){
        fragmentsList.add(fragment);
        fragsTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragsTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentsList.size();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea to solving this problem?

Thanks.

### Edit:

Problem solved by removing NestedScrollingView from coordinator layout in `activity_main` and putting that in fragment layout (inside viewpager).
But still I don't know why device back button did not worked in former state.

Comment: your issue can't be caused by adding a viewpager. Look for a problem somewhere else

Comment: does you overridde onbackpress() method?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I spent 3 days on it and tried anything I could but no result! (I'm new in android developing)
Without setting adapter to ViewPager, everything is working fine. Also when I deleted NestedScrollView and put ViewPager in coordinator layout, again back button is working.
If you have any idea please teell me to try it.

Comment: @ArsalanKhan No. (I tried it for solving problem by something like finishing activity(Although destroying activity is not my purpose!), but I was not successful.)

Comment: Try Overriding the onBackPressed() of the activity and call super, and print something. see If the onBackpressed is being called

Comment: @ColonD I override it for closing navigation drawer and saw that its not working! have you an idea that why it is not working?!

Comment: Does your Fragment have its own onBackPressed()?

Comment: @I can not understand your meaning! Does fragment have onBackPressed() methode?!
Anyway my fragment was empty and I did not wrote any code in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is occurring because you have used a third party library for ViewPager.
Just copy and paste the following code in the place of your "activity_main.xml" file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main2" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have initialized fragment to ViewPager like this

```
ViewPager viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter2 = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pagerAdapter2.addFragment(TestFragment.createInstance(),"Home");
    viewPager2.setAdapter(pagerAdapter2);
    TabLayout tabLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout2.setupWithViewPager(viewPager2);
```

Here is the Testfragment.java class

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

public static TestFragment createInstance() {
    TestFragment profileFragment = new TestFragment();
    return profileFragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jadvalyab, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}
}
```

And the full code of "Main2Activity.java" class is here

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    initViewPager();
}

private void initViewPager() {
    ViewPager viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter2 = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pagerAdapter2.addFragment(TestFragment.createInstance(),"Home");
    viewPager2.setAdapter(pagerAdapter2);
    TabLayout tabLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout2.setupWithViewPager(viewPager2);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Edit:

Code of "content_main2.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Code for "fragment_jadvalyab.xml" is in te following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="Best Wishes"
android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time. I changed my third party viewpager to standard viewpager, but it doesn't work. Can you add your `content_main2.xml` and fragment layout code please?
Maybe I have a wrong attribute in my xml files.

Comment: It is great to know that it was useful for you.Thank you.I have edited my answer please take a look on it.

Comment: When I putted ViewPager in NestedScrollView, again everythin works fine except device back button!
Anyway thank you for your time. Problem solved by deleting NestedScrollView from CoordinatorLayout and putting that in fragment layout.

Comment: I tested the program which I have given .In my device it was working fine with the back buttonNow you have solved it ,that's good.

Comment: Probably I made a mistake somewhere. I will test it again ASAP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Your Action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPress(){} event in your MainActivity which holds your above xml layout.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override `OnBackPressed()` method , or you can write your adapter as this.

```
 public class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public Adapter (FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
 // you can add fragments according to your requirement
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment= null;
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragment= new fragmentDay();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment= new fragmentWeek();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment= new fragmentMonth();
            break;

    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

}

and inside activity pass fragment manager to adapter constructor.

```
    fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
    adapter= new Adapter(fragmentManager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have used tablayout with viewpager

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Day");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("Week");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText("Month");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select(); 
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what is wrong in my adapter?!
When I'm adding fragments to viewpager, codes that is written in onBackPress() doesn't run.
(‌But it can close soft keyboard!)

Comment: I am not sure about your adapter. I will test it ASAP and will tell you if there is any problem in your adapter. Is my adapter  working for you?

Comment: Reza I think problem is not from adapter. I tested your adapter and it is working fine (like my own adapter), but back button doesn't work again.